# Multi-conditional algorithm

Tags: php, algorithm, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have some groups of clothing sizes that I need to distinguish (in order to sort them appropriately later, based on their type)...

So, the sizes can be:

- Ranges (ie. `S-M` or `M-L`, or even `8.5-9.5` - generally two *things* with a dash between them...)
- Textual (ie. `S` or `M` or `XL` etc...)
- Numeric (ie. `38` or `42 1/2` or `39.5` or `40 2/3` or `7` or `5''` or `3"` - the last two are measured in inches and are stored either with two single quotes or one double quote)
- Verbose (ie. `One-size` or `Size five` or `Size seven`)
- Sizeless (ie. the array that would hold the sizes is empty for some reason)

So I came up with the algorithm below that does exactly that, but looks a bit ugly...

```
foreach ($products as $prod) {
    $is_range = true;
    $is_textual = true;
    $is_numeric = true;
    $is_verbose = true;

    if (count($prod['sizes'])) {
        foreach ($prod['sizes'] as $_size) {
            if (strpos($_size, '-') === false) {
                $is_range = false;

                if (!in_array($_size, array('3XS', '2XS', 'XXXS', 'XXS', 'XS', 'S', 'M', 'L', 'XL', 'XXL', 'XXXL', '2XL', '3XL'))) {
                    $is_textual = false;

                    if (!preg_match("/\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?: \d+\/\d+)?(?:''|\")?/", $_size)) {
                        $is_numeric = false;

                        if (stripos($_size, 'size') === false) {
                            $is_verbose = false;
                        } else {
                            $is_range = false;
                            $is_textual = false;
                            $is_numeric = false;
                        }
                    } else {
                        $is_range = false;
                        $is_textual = false;
                        $is_verbose = false;
                    }
                } else {
                    $is_range = false;
                    $is_numeric = false;
                    $is_verbose = false;
                }
            } else {
                $is_textual = false;
                $is_numeric = false;
                $is_verbose = false;
            }
        }
    } else {
        $is_range = false;
        $is_textual = false;
        $is_numeric = false;
        $is_verbose = false;
    }
}
```

Can someone come up with a better/shorter/smarter approach? TIA

Comment: It looks like if you defaulted the various `$is_` variables to false instead of true, and reversed the conditions, you could get rid of all of the `else` parts.

Comment: I did it this way to make sure that if even one size of the group is braking one condition, the condition will never get `true` again... Otherwise, if the admin that operates the system, by mistake, mixes two different types of sizes (ie `M` and `42`) for the same product, the whole sorting process that follows will not be performed...